# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy policy would block the window.closed call. Error while using sign in with Google using Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i have created an app in which have a signIn page in that i used the sign in with google using firebase, the pop up is opening and i am getting the data of the user (like email,profilePicture,name etc) in localhost but it is showing the COOP error when i deployed the app in the deployed app even the popup is not opening.

The firebase config file

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyBZT5DK41D11J22xZNuOKJKKJH76876AKAgx_YQU',
  authDomain: 'assignment-52Aaf.firebaseapp.com',
  projectId: 'assignment-52Aaf',
  storageBucket: 'nodejs-assignment-52Aaf.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '107073953731',
  appId: '1:107073953731:web:60b9aca7b1fc817545642776',
  measurementId: 'G-PV07X25JLKK',

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { auth, provider };
```

This is the signInPage specifically the handleSignWithGoogle (And dont worry i have imported all the modules that why it is working in localhost)

```
const handleSignWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await signInWithPopup(auth,provider);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.user.displayName);
        setUser({
         name: data.user.displayName,
         email: data.user.email,
       });
       setToken(data.user.accessToken);
       navigate('/home');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error signing in with Google:', error);
    }
  };
```

I have tried everything but did not able to correct the error